# Difference between "welcome to", "welcome on" and "welcome at"

Tags: meaning

As in the title. What's the main difference between them? What should I use when I'm greeting someone on/at my website?

Answer (score 4):

"Welcome to ..." is a greeting. For your website, you most likely want to say "Welcome to MyWebsite.com!"

"Welcome to ...!" You are excited someone is there.

"You are welcome at my home anytime!" You are saying that you would be happy to see them anytime they want to stop by. "You are welcome at my home" sounds a bit like a robotic way to say "Welcome to my home!"

"You are welcome on ..." This tells someone they are allowed to be on a certain thing. "You are welcome on my plane." "You are welcome on my land." You would not say "You are welcome on my house" because they will not be on your house. They can be in your house or at your house but people are not on your house. Although they could be on the roof of your house.

Comment: please elaborate

Comment: I would say "Welcome to" when I am welcoming someone somewhere. Like "Welcome to my home." I would not say "Welcome at my home." I could say "You are welcome at my home." But this has a different connotation. It sounds a bit more robotic and it is more like giving someone permission to be there than saying you are happy they are there. I would never say "Welcome on my home." I might say "You are welcome on my boat." On would be used to speak about being on an object like a boat, or plane.

Comment: If you are actually welcoming the person just by saying the phrase (performative use) it's always *welcome to*. If you are instead telling the person that they will always be welcome somewhere, the preposition will depend on the place. *thanks so much for letting me stay so long* / *oh what are you talking about, you know you're always welcome in my house* does not sound that robotic to me, although *here* would be more natural.